# Finding the distance a projectile penetrated through an object from projectile's direction and object's rotation.

Tags: geometry

[image]

In the picture, the red line represents the direction of the projectile, and I need to find the distance between the two blue lines from the direction of the projectile and the rotation of the object. I literally don't have any clue on how to do that.

Comment: It would be far better if you could upload the image here, in the body of your question, and not provide a link. Also providing some context, where does the problem come from etc.

Comment: I am very new to this stack websites, not sure how to upload an image in the body of my question, I clicked on the image option and stack asked me for an image and I just gave the image of my problem

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the numerical dimensions and parameters for the problem. Also, what do you mean by "the object's rotation"? By any chance, do you mean "orientation"?

Comment: the problem comes from a game engine, I need to know the position where the projectile exists the object after penetrating through, the game engine doesn't provide the exist position of the projectile, only the enter point, so I need to calculate that myself, to find the exist point I need to find the distance the projectile has penetrated

Comment: If the projectile enters at angle $\theta$ with respect to horizontal, and the width of the rectangle is $w$ then the distance between entry point and exit point of the projectile is  $w\sec\theta$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***If*** I have understood what you want and what the problem's hypothesis are properly, and with the help of my rather poor drawing below, then the question is reduced to finding the hypotenuse $x$ of a right triangle given one angle ($r-t$) and one side ($d$). This can be directly obtained via the cosine as: $|\cos(r-t)|=\Large\frac d{x}$ $\Rightarrow x=\Large\frac d{|\cos(r-t)|}$

I have made the (non-clarified assumptions) that we know the width $d$ of this rectangular object, the degree of rotation of the object $r$ (the angle it forms with the lime colored horizontal line of reference), and the direction of the projectile $t$.

[image]

Comment: May I ask is *t* the angle of the direction of the projectile according to the rotation of the object?

Comment: gosh I wish I had gone to school, anyways, where did you get the 2nd rectangular object from?

Comment: @XoxoMomo $t$ is indeed the direction of the projectile, but I consider it a fixed (given value). Then we have the rotation of the object being $r$. To be honest, I think putting the cosine in absolute is a better formulation to avoid any negative values. I will edit. I just drew it on paint! School can teach a few skills but erase a lot others so, no worries.